# Probability of choosing two numbers from a bag such that neither number is double the other

Tags: probability

Two numbers are randomly selected from bag which has numbers from $1$ to $20$ , what is the probability that one number is not twice the other ?

My turn :

$$
\begin{aligned}
& 1-p(\text{one is twice the other})
\\
&\qquad= 1 - p[(1,2)\ ,\ (2,4)\ ,\ (4,8)\ ,\ (6,12)\  ,\ (8,16)\ ,\ 
         (9,18)\ ,\ (10 ,20)]
\\
&\qquad= 1 -\frac{1}{20}\times \frac{1}{19}\times 2 \times 10 
\\
&\qquad= \frac{18}{19}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Is that correct ?

Comment: What is the probability of the cases $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(2,1)$? And what does that tuple $(1,2)$ mean inside the "probability of something"? (Notation should be clear, the reader has to fix it else, its one meaning among two, remember it, and when it comes to using the meaning to pick the right one.)

Comment: Your answer is correct but your reasoning is unclear to me. A more natural calculation would start with how many pairs there are. Then there are just $10$ you want to omit.

Comment: I have subtracted the probability that one number is double the other from 1 @Ethan Bolker

Comment: $\displaystyle 1 - \frac{10}{\binom{20}{2}}.$

Comment: @HussienMohamed I know that's what you were thinking, since you got the right answer. But your equation does not tell the reader why you wrote it down the way you did.